# MultiThreaded Server, which is a client to another server

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client, java-server

I'm using a server socket to accept clients on the main thread, when a thread is accepted,the clients socket is given to a handler which is started in a new thread to process communications. However, before I start running my server to access clients, it connects to a second server which it must list to and be able to respond to and pass on the messages it gets to it's clients.

Hopefully this image illustrate what I mean:

[image: Image of client server client model]

The small server must be continuously listening for input from the big server, and also able to output responses.

```
//Default constructor
private smallServer(){}

//method to initialise and start the server
public static void StartServer(int port) throws IOException {
    smallServer ss = new smallServer();
    ss.bs= new bigServerClient(ss);
    Thread nsc_Thread = new Thread(ss.bsc);
    bsc_Thread.start();
    //accepts clients and starts new thread for them
    ss.ServerRun(port);
        }

private void ServerRun(int port) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(port);
    server.setSoTimeout(50);
    while (run) {
        Socket client = null;
        try {
            client = server.accept();
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        }

        if (client != null) {
            ClientHandler handler = new ClientHandler(client, this);
            Thread handleThread = new Thread(handler);
            handleThread.start();
        }
    }

    if (!run) {
        synchronized (ClientHandler.handlers) {
            for (ClientHandler handler : ClientHandler.handlers) {
                handler.terminateHandler();
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void processBigServerCommand(String toProcess) {
    System.out.println("RESEAVED: " + toProcess);
}
```

The big server client(on the small server) then does this:

```
public class bigServerClient implements Runnable {

    private smalsServer ss;
    private PrintWriter printer;
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private Socket socket;

    public bigServerClient(smallServer _ss) throws IOException {
        ss = _ss;
        socket = new Socket("Localhost", 5000);
        printer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        printer.flush();
        SendBigServerMessage("Starting String");
    }

    private void SendBigServerMessage(String toSend) {
        printer.print(toSend);
        printer.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (ss.state()) {
                String inputLine;
                while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    ss.processBigServerCommand(inputLine);
                    System.out.println(inputLine);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From what's above, can anyone see why the big server client isn't responding to the big server when a message is sent? I'm guessing it's something to do with the main thread blocking the second thread, but I'm not sure... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the code for the smallserver?

Comment: Opps! Forgot that bit, I've added it above now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You lost me in your code...
Simplify it.
Your `smallServer` (see class names conventions) should have persistent connection to `BigServer` (effectively it is `BigServer` client) - you can implement it in your `smallServer` class, it should connect (once) and open I/O to `BigServer` (once) and close everything once the connection is terminated.
As your `smallServer` will handle multiple clients and pass their requests to `BigServer` there is no guarantee of the order of `BigServer` responses - you should do something to handle that (maybe pass UUID with requests?)
Simplify your `smallServer` and make sure that it runs...

Comment: Yeah, I think it's overly complicated myself, but it was just the way I managed to hack it together. I made the small server act like a server to all the clients and that works, but while it's doing that, I can't seem to get it to communicate with the big server, I'm not too worried about passing messages between the clients and the big server, I just need the small server to be able to talk to clients and the big server (Sorry about the names, I should of called them bottom middle and top :P

Comment: Re-edit your code and add missing methods.  
`SmallServer` should implement Runnable too and so should `ClientHandler`.  
Make sure that the code compiles and it should run, there are no obvious problems that should prevent it from running...